# ArcGIS Javascript API: Adding a class to a graphic node

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

In building my map interface, I have opted to use the built in graphics layer for simplicity.  I would like to do some operations on the markers (show and hide based on filter toggles), but have no simple way to differentiate them.  Is there a way to programmatically add classes to each marker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Attributes are optional, but can easily be included in a JSON object when you are creating the graphic.

[Example from the API Reference page:](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#graphic1)

```
require([
  "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/Color", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/graphic", ... 
], function(Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Color, InfoTemplate, Graphic, ... ) {
  var pt = new Point(xloc,yloc,map.spatialReference)
  var sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(
    SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE).setColor(
    new Color([255,0,0,0.5]));
  var attr = {"Xcoord":evt.mapPoint.x,"Ycoord":evt.mapPoint.y,"Plant":"Mesa Mint"};
  var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Vernal Pool Locations","Latitude: ${Ycoord} <br/>
    Longitude: ${Xcoord} <br/>
    Plant Name:${Plant}");
  var graphic = new Graphic(pt,sms,attr,infoTemplate);
  ...
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I am looking for.  I've already been including attributes.  However, the graphic itself never contains any of this information. It's just an svg element.  What I want to know is how to act on those attributes, or otherwise modify the html to be accessible to outside js.

Comment: Storing data to be queried and manipulated isn't really what a graphics layer is for, although you can query it to make a new graphics layer that shows the subset of data... or make multiple graphics layers that can be individually controlled by toggles... I'm not really aware of a good way to make that simple, or at least not simpler than querying a map service.

Comment: The graphic's attributes should be in "attributes" property e.g. graphic.attributes.id or graphics.attributes['id']

Answer (score 0):

As Erica has pointed out you can set the attribute values and use those for filtering / identifying graphics and that is likely to be the simplest way. If you want to use CSS for styling your graphics there is a [help article](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_styling_svg.html) about this as well as a few different samples on the API site